# Product with Multiple Product Related using Laravel Model HasMany() & BelongsTo?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

As of now I have 2 different `Model`

`ProductModel.php` Which is my list of products.

`ProductRelated.php` Which is the assigned related product per specific product.

The scenario is,

If I have `id = 1` in my `ProductModel`. `id (primary key of Product Model)`

and in my `ProductRelated.php` I have this

`prodID` (Which is the equivalent of `id (primary key of Product Model)`
This will serve to identify which specific product id the related products are being assiged.

`prodRelatedID` this is the products related to that product.

So my `ProductModel` will have this data

```
  id | prodTitle | prodDesc    | More fields here...
   1 | Product 1 | Description | More FIeld value here ..
   2 | Product 2 | Description | More FIeld value here ..
   3 | Product 3 | Description | More FIeld value here ..
```

In my `ProductRelated` will have this data

```
  id | prodID | prodRelatedID | More fields here...
   1 | 1      | 2             | More FIeld value here ..
   2 | 1      |  3            | More FIeld value here ..
```

Which means, `id = 1` from `ProductModel` has 2 different `prodRelatedID`

and those are the `2 and 3`

My idea by doing this is to use `hasMany()`

Here's my `ProductModel`

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class ProductModel extends Model
{
public $timestamps = true;
protected $table = 'product';
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'prodTitle',
    'prodDesc',
    'prodCategory',
    'attachment',
    'prodSize',
    'prodPrice',
    'created_by',
    'is_best_seller',
    
    'prod_included',
    'prod_instruction',
];
}
```

My `ProductRelated`

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class ProductRelated extends Model
{
public $timestamps = true;
protected $table = 'product_related';
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'prodID',
    'prodRelatedID',
    'created_by'
];

}
```

Comment: what are u asking?

Comment: This sounds to me like a many to many.

Comment: Yes, many to many if im not mistaken. I just want to get all related products per specific product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get all related products per specific product, I do not think you need `ProductRelated`.

In your `ProductModel`

```php
    public function relatedProducts()
    {
            return $this->belongsToMany(ProductModel::class, 'product_related', 'prodID', 'prodRelatedID');
    }
```

And then you should be able to get all records like this:

```php
$relatedProducts = ProductModel::find(1)->relatedProducts()->get();
```

Comment: Can I put `where()` in here?

Comment: @RaeIan yes, for the Product? or relatedProducts?

Comment: I have this deleted field in my Product and Also in my related Products. Trying to put where product deleted is equal to 0 and related product deleted is equal to 0

Comment: @RaeIan `ProductModel::where('deleted', 0)->relatedProducts()->where('deleted', 0)->get();` this may work.